# Save text that is not in table form as tsv file

Tags: r

I have a probably dummy question. Is it possible to save multiple text lines in a tsv file?My dataframe is:

```
master <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), B=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8),C=c(5,2,5,7,7,5,7,9,7,8),D=c(1,2,5,3,7,5,9,6,7,0))

    write.table(
for(i in 1:nrow(master)){
  writeLines(c(paste("A",master[i,1]),
               paste("B",master[i,2]),
               paste("C",master[i,3]),
               paste("D",master[i,4])
  ))
},
file="Rat.tsv", quote=FALSE, sep='\t', col.names = NA
)
```

When I do it I get as a result an empty file with 2B size but the expected
output should be like below: At least this is what I get before using `write.table()`.

```
A 1
B 1
C 5
D 1
A 1
B 2
C 2
D 2
A 2
B 3
C 5
D 5
A 2
B 3
C 7
D 3
A 3
B 4
C 7
D 7
A 3
B 5
C 5
D 5
A 4
B 6
C 7
D 9
A 4
B 6
C 9
D 6
A 5
B 7
C 7
D 7
A 5
B 8
C 8
D 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `writeLines` function writes to stdout and returns `NULL` which is probably what is ending up in the tsv file. Removing the `writeLines` call yields this code which does write something to the file.

```
write.table(
    x=c(paste("Duplicate Set:"),
        paste("Source data rows:"),
        paste("Rows differ with respect to Column(s)")
    ),
    file="Rat.tsv", quote=FALSE, sep='\t', col.names = NA)
```

Comment: I edited my Q since it is not possible to create the tsv in the form that I want. I created a reproducible example closer to the requested output

Comment: The `writeLines` function is still returning `NULL` which is what will end up in the tsv file. Perhaps you could post an example of what you want to see in this file?

Comment: I added this.tnx

Answer (score 1):

I recycled this from an old function, so it may not be the best way, but this appears to create the output that you provided:

```
master <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), B=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8),C=c(5,2,5,7,7,5,7,9,7,8),D=c(1,2,5,3,7,5,9,6,7,0))

### Close any connections
closeAllConnections()

### Make file name and open connection
fileName_v <- "test.tsv"
file_conn <- file(fileName_v)

for (i in 1:nrow(master)) {

  ### Make line
  out <- c(paste("A",master[i,1]),
           paste("B",master[i,2]),
           paste("C",master[i,3]),
           paste("D",master[i,4]))

  ### Write line
  if (i == 1) {
    writeLines(out, file_conn)
  } else {
    file_conn <- file(fileName_v, "a")
    write(out, file_conn, append = T)
  }
}

closeAllConnections()
```